# C# asynchronous functions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

I am currently executing a long process asynchronously using delegates. this process could be invoked several times depending on given data (numbers of employees for example) my question is about the impact on performance for creating a list of delegates responsible for executing the process.

Comment: How big are we talking here, realistically? If it's a handful, then I wouldn't worry about it, but if the number's pretty large, you might think about using `ThreadPool`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When invoking a delegate asynchronously you are using a thread from the thread pool. Estimating the performance impact of this on your application will of course depend on your application. For example in ASP.NET reducing the number of worker threads could have negative impact since there will be less threads available to service requests.

Comment: so in case there is a traffic on my site (which is the current case) all resources in the ThreadPool would be totally consumed?

Comment: @SShebly, once again it depends, but holding threads from the thread pool for long periods of time could have negative impact on performance of a web application.